# Can gnome windows (in Ubuntu) be individually themed?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, themes

(Yes, "individually themed" is an oxymoron, but I still want it.)

I've just moved from Windows to Ubuntu Linux, and although I am enjoying this new adventure playground, I've encountered something quite unexpected... and its bugging me.

It is probably because there are so many gnome apps in Ubuntu (... how strange :)
This is great. and the range of available apps is excellent! ...but because of this one-stop-shop scenario, most of the windows look remarkably similar.
I'm certainly not after bling-maximus, but I would like a few differentiating colours for my not-so-young eyes to help identify an app at a glance (especially in the compiz lists) ... I love compiz :) I thought it was just a bit of razzle-dazzle, and that alone would be enough, but it is actually very practical to boot.

So, basically, I'm wondering if there is a way to theme individual window components on a per app basis... especially the window decoration; menu bar, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of different things coming together to make the particular look of a given Window. There's the Window Decorator, which depending your set up, could be different (e.g., Emerald, or gnome-window-decorator, etc.) There's also things like the gtk-theme, which defines things like the colorscheme and icons. I don't know whether or not there's a way to have different window decorators for different programs, though you can turn it off for certain windows (using Compiz's Window Decoration plugin). You can certainly use different gtk themes for different applications. [See here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/how-do-i-execute-a-program-in-gnome-and-make-it-use-another-gtk-theme-other-than)

Comment: Oh frabjous day! Callooh! Callay! - I chortle in my joy...  It works!  So far I can get different menu colours via the GTK themes, and I've yet to investigate Compiz's Window Decoration.  Even the menu tweak alone is helpful enough.. Thanks... I'll go and gyre an gimble a bit with it now...